# Query in JSONB array of Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, json-query

Below JSON is one of the column of type JSONB in my table 'logic', I want to query to check how many rows are there with `type`: `QUESTION` (any entry within `conditions`).

```
{
  "name": null,
  "conditions": [
    {
      "type": "QUESTION",
      "question": {
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "QUESTION",
      "question": {
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "FIELD",
      "question": {
      }
    }
  ],
  "expression": "A"
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the number of times `"type": "QUESTION"` entry appears within `conditions` of the `jsonb` column throughout the table.

```
select count(*) FROM logic CROSS JOIN LATERAL
 jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_col->'conditions')as j(typ) 
WHERE j->>'type'  = 'QUESTION'
```

If you want to check the number of times `"type": "QUESTION"` entry appears within `conditions` for each row.

```
select jsonb_col,count(*) FROM logic CROSS JOIN LATERAL
 jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_col->'conditions')as j(typ) 
WHERE j->>'type'  = 'QUESTION'
group by jsonb_col
```

If you want to check how many rows have at least one entry within conditions with 
`'type'  = 'QUESTION'`,

```
select count(*) FROM
(
 select DISTINCT jsonb_col FROM logic CROSS JOIN LATERAL
 jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_col->'conditions')as j(typ) 
WHERE j->>'type'  = 'QUESTION'
)s;
```

Use the query which you find is appropriate for you

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c12ea22138797429f362844f55c5c760)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, it worked like a CHAMP :)